# How to access HTML controls with no ID or name?

Tags: vbscript

I am writing a VBScript to access a website and do some operations

```
Dim IE
Dim Helem
Dim hwnd
Dim Wnd

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
hwnd = IE.hwnd

IE.Visible = 1 
IE.Navigate "MySite.com"

Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4
    WScript.Sleep 10
Loop

IE.document.getElementById("username").value = "user"
```

After which i have to click on a hyperlink which has no ID or name in the HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="some URL">click me 1</a>
    <a href="some URL">click me 2</a>
    <a href="some URL">click me 3/a>
    <a href="some URL">click me 4</a>
</div>
```

Can someone help me with this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the easiest way would be to inject the appropriate id tag into the given HTML but in the event that you do not have access or permission to do so you can always use document.childNodes and iterate through the DOM directly to find the element that you care about.

```
 Set myRootNode = IE.document.getElementById("menu").childNodes();

  For i = 0 To myRootNode.length - 1

      if (myRootNode(i).innerText == "click me 1" ) then
          myRootNode(i).doClick()
      end if

  Next i
```

The "doClick()" part is most likely incorrect due to the fact that I have not actually touched vb ( or any microsoft operating system for that matter) for cleanly over a decade. but this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Damian!, Can you please give a code sample for document.childNodes, i have updated my codesample in the question

Comment: does this work even for VBScript? i tried but its not working. i tried putting in a message box after set myRootNode, msgbox myRootNode.Length

Comment: it should, take a look at the MSDN documentation  for exact syntax but the w3c DOM api is implemented almost identically in a dozen languages.

Comment: Not sure i am getting error at line msgbox myRootNode(i).innerText, Error "Class doesn't support Automation"

Comment: Can you printout myRootNode(i) ? if so then its the call to innertext, I did a quick google and it appears that innerHTML is supported. so try that.

Comment: No i am not able to.. i did msgbox myRootNode(i) i am getting the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72038/discussion-between-damian-nikodem-and-ssk).